# Error in Installing Jenkins

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, jenkins

I was installing Jenkins and run the following command, I got following error-

```
utsav@utsav-HP-Laptop-14s-cr2xxx:~$ wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
utsav@utsav-HP-Laptop-14s-cr2xxx:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
utsav@utsav-HP-Laptop-14s-cr2xxx:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:4 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release                     
Err:5 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release.gpg                 
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5BA31D57EF5975CA
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                    
Hit:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5BA31D57EF5975CA
W: Failed to fetch https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/Release.gpg  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5BA31D57EF5975CA
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
utsav@utsav-HP-Laptop-14s-cr2xxx:~$ sudo systemctl status jenkins
× jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-09-19 22:18:12 IST; 9min>
    Process: 33163 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 33163 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 107ms

Sep 19 22:18:12 utsav-HP-Laptop-14s-cr2xxx systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Schedul>
Sep 19 22:18:12 utsav-HP-Laptop-14s-cr2xxx systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuo>
Sep 19 22:18:12 utsav-HP-Laptop-14s-cr2xxx systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Start r>
Sep 19 22:18:12 utsav-HP-Laptop-14s-cr2xxx systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed >
Sep 19 22:18:12 utsav-HP-Laptop-14s-cr2xxx systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins >
lines 1-12/12 (END)
```

Comment: Take it up with the owner of the PPA.